# Datapager in Silverlight language Change

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have silverlight page in which i am using datapager. User wants to change the datapager text[Page[1]to 3] "Page" to their language(turkish).
how can we achieve this because the datapager loaded from  system.data.dll.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123046/Localization-in-Silverlight) which explains how to localize silverlight application by using [Resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) & *CultureInfo*.

Comment: I did the localization for whole project but cant change the datapager "page" text alone. pls help for this..

Comment: can't you put values in your resource files for this specific change ?

Comment: Datapager loading using system.data.dll namespace for that how can i resource. thats my question.

Comment: ok for that you need to extract datapage control template through expression blend OR here is the [reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894495(v=vs.95).aspx "DataPager Styles and Templates") which gives you datapager style resource. Alternatively, please see this [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952724/change-datapager-text "Custom DataPager"). let me know if any issue